# Seeking a manual way to update xib (custom view) cocoatouch class files in interface builder?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, xcode13

Is there any way to manually force all xib files to update to the latest Xcode tools versions, for example, when you upgrade to the new Xcode 13, there are some bugs with certain xib views if you have an outdated tools version (tools version from previous Xcode versions say).

In addition, the updates bring improvements and if you have an app with a decent amount of custom views, it’s nice to not have to individually tap on each one of them and open each one of them to update..